# How make dump of physical memory

Tags: virtual-machine, dump, qemu

I'd like make dump of physical memory using Qemu. Can I make it with use of virsh? For ex., virsh dump --memory-only? And can I make live dump with use of this feature? Unfortunately, using virsh qemu-monitor-command  --hmp "pmemsave 0 0x80000000 win7.dump" calls error: Can't open win7.dump, permission denied.